# Add Variable to Object Literal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a variable to an object I'm creating, but when I log the object `id` appears simply as `id`, instead of my `ref.key()` value.

```
var id = ref.key();

var newItem = {
  'provider1': {
    'services': {
      id: true
    }
  }
};

console.log(newItem);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: keys are literal, if you want to use a variable you have to use bracket notation, as in `newItem.provider1.services[id] = true`

Comment: What *is* your `ref.key()` value?

Comment: use the indexer. `[id]`.

Comment: you are setting your `id` property to `true`, not to the variable `id`, probably should be `id:id`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I intentionally want to set my `id` to `true`.

Comment: @adeneo I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'services' of undefined`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k6yucv9h/2/

Comment: Then can you expand on what you are wanting, what are you expecting to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use bracket notation:

```
var id = ref.key();

var newItem = {
  'provider1': {
    'services': {}
  }
};
newItem.provider1.services[id] = true;

console.log(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = ref.key();
```

and

```
'services': {
      id: true
    }
```

Have absolutely nothing to do with each other. One is a `variable` while the other is an `object key name` that you are setting to `true`.

```
'services': {
      id: id // <-- this id has your ref.key() value
    }
```

Would make more sense.